# knife bootstrap returning error

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, knife

Running:

```
knife bootstrap ec2-54-221-16-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com --sudo -x chef -P chef -N server --run-list 'role[inicial]'
```

My recipes/default.rb:

```
script "teste de script" do
  interpreter "bash"
  cwd "/home/ubuntu"
  code <<-EOH
  as-create-launch-config LcTiagoN --image-id ami-0521316c --instance-type t1.micro --key tiagov
  EOH
end
```

My roles/inicial.rb:

```
name "inicial"

run_list "recipe[my_cookbook]"
```

The following error occurs below:

```
ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed←[
0m
------------------------------------←[
0m
Expected process to exit with [0], but
 received '127'
 ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/che
f-script20140501-8463-12uvvvl" ----
 STDOUT:
STDERR: /tmp/chef-script20140501-8463-
12uvvvl: line 1: as-create-launch-config: command not found
 ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-
script20140501-8463-12uvvvl" ----
```

However when I run the same command (as-create-launch-config LcTiagoN --image-id ami-0521316c --instance-type t1.micro --key tiagov) directly logged in the Amazon instance, the command is executed successfully.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with the PATH environment. Did you login as "chef" when running the *as-create-launch-config* command manually?

Best advice I can offer is to include the full path to the command in the bash script. For example:

```
script "teste de script" do
  ..
  code <<-EOH
  /path/to/this/cmd/as-create-launch-config ...
  EOH
end
```

Comment: I ran the test described below, what do you think it might be?

Comment: It's not a permissions issue, it's a PATH issue. In *nix environments, the way executables are found is by making sure they're available in PATH. You can try "echo $PATH" to see what the PATH is at any given moment.

I bet if you run recipes/default above but add echo the PATH just before running as-create-launch-config you'll find the PATH does not include whatever directory as-create-launch-config exists in.

Then you just need to ssh into the machine, type "which as-create-launch-config" to get the path, then add that path to your recipe like Mark did above.

Comment: I'm having a problem with my environment variables.

Because the variables are being lost? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @TiagoRolim It's possible to set environment variables as part of the script resource. This is must better (more portable) rather than relying on settings in an environment file. (See: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_script.html)